# Most efficient way to read a specific column in large csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

There is a CSV file approx. size of 2,5 GB with about 50 columns and 4,5 million rows.

The dataset will be used for different operations, but at once just a few columns are used, therefore I am looking for a high performant algorithm to read only one column in a CSV file.

1. Reading the file in one chunk takes roughly 38 seconds to read it in a Pandas dataframe.

   > ```
   > path = r"C:\my_path\my_csv.csv"
   > pd.read_csv(path, header=0)
   > ```
2. Reading only one specific column takes about 14 seconds

   > `pd.read_csv(path, usecols=["my_specific_col"], header=0)`

Is there a way to reduce the reading time? As it seems that the number of columns has little effect on the performance.

Comment: Maybe you should use PySpark or Dask as they read data lazily. Did you try to read file with `csv` module?

Comment: the csv module is worth, as it reads line-by-line, so basically you have to read the full file. PySpark or Dask is a completely different approach, I think for offline applications pandas should be fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 1.4.0 of Pandas, there is a new experimental engine for [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), relying on the Arrow library’s CSV multithreaded parser instead of the default C parser.

So, this might help to speed things up:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(path, usecols=["my_specific_col"], header=0, engine="pyarrow")
```

Comment: The pyarrow engine reduces the loading time to a 1/10th compared to the default engine