# Error when read a single column from a huge CSV file with Pandas and PyArrow engine

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pyarrow

I am trying to read in Pandas a single column from a huge CSV file using the answer from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75029194/most-efficient-way-to-read-a-specific-column-in-large-csv-file):

```
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", usecols=["id_str"], engine="pyarrow")
```

and I obtain this error:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: CSV parse error: Expected 4 columns, got 3
```

Using a much smaller file, I can read it using just `pd.read_csv` without any option.

Reading around it seems this problem is related to the fact that the CSV file has empty cells, which are filled by `NaN` when `pd.read_csv` is used without options, but they create problems in the other case.

I didn't find any solution yet for this problem, any sugestions?

I want to read just some columns, because the file is really huge and I need just those for the analysis I have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSV file is broken. Somewhere down the file, you have an incorrect number of commas... so there are less columns than pandas would expect. You cannot reproduce this error with a (different) smaller file, because that smaller data (e.g., only the top 100 rows) are formatted correctly - so your code works. Somewhere down below in your original file, at least one row is not looking like the rows above, and that causes the error (only on the original file).

This is **not** about missing values (e.g., `np.NaN`, represented in csv as `",,"`). These can be parsed. It's about incorrect number of commas in a row.

Assume you want to fix the file, you will need to find the broken row (and either remove it, or fix the content). Try to read just a certain number of rows (top 100, 500, 1000, ..) until you hit the error. That will let you find the row. Or make a copy of the file, and delete the bottom 90%, bottom 80%, .. until the error pops up.

Comment: Hi @KingOtto, I could reproduce the error because the smaller file contain it. If I read it without options everything is fine, but if I try to read just one column the error pops up. Checking better the file, I found out that the line with the error is a text message over more than one line. If I manually modify it putting everything on one line, without adding or removing any comma, everything works...
I am trying to understand how to automatically fix it, but I am quite puzzled.
Thanks again for your help

Comment: what do you mean "a line that goes over more than one line"? sounds like the text editor that you are using makes a line break (e.g., Notepad on Windows)? if you use a different editor (notepad++), do you still see "more than one line"? the only way to actually break a line into two lines would be the newline special character "\n". otherwise you may just not be using an adequate editor to inspect files with very long lines. One possible automatic detection (if that is even your problem) would be to remove all "\n" occurrences in your file. Again, only if they are truly there

Comment: yes there were newline special characters "\n", I checked with notepad++.
I replaced them with whitespace with `test["text"].replace(r"\n", " ", regex=True)` and, at least for now, it seems working.
For sure there will be other problems later :-) I really appreciate your help, thanks a lot